# Less CSS cleaner?

Tags: less

I now have 4000 lines of "less" -- it's primarily just CSS, with only a few newer bits taking advantage of Less' functionality.

I'd like to clean it up -- nest any rules that are nestable, for example. I've found [css2less](http://css2less.cc/) but my code is too big for it, and the command-line version actually generates invalid Less.

Are there any alternatives? Either less->less cleaner, or css->less converter/cleaner?

Comment: as great as it is to nest selectors, you're better off splitting off code into separate files, and using the lowest specificity selector you possibly can. Keep your styles down to a single class or attribute selector as much as possible, and you'll find that it scales much better for larger projects.

Comment: This project is about 9 years old now... doing the best I can with the time I have available :-) Splitting the file is a good idea though. It's essentially free now that we've switched over to less. I'd still like a tool to help clean it up though; I can't go through this whole thing by hand.

Comment: The best result is you going through all the css and migrating it manually, tools are not the greatest solution. You think you don't have time to do it manually but you'll spend more time figuring out what some tool did to your original styles ;)

Comment: Totally agree with @AlexanderMarinenko, tools are nice, but.. Personally i'd start by splitting it into smaller less files organized by functionality modules (forum, ads, comments, ..) once that done you can redo multiple passes to fine grain it even more (layout, colors scheme, etc). It's quite some work, but pays off quickly when later intervening on the css since you know exactly where to look instead of sifting through a 3mile long css file. Anyways .. a css file renamed .less, well is a less file :)

Comment: @Robert: That's more or less what I did to start (rename the file). It didn't like a few of the IE hacks :-) I guess I will slowly clean it up over time then.

Comment: Give a try to the css2less Ruby gem if 4000 lines are too much for other tools.

Comment: @menjaraz: It produces invalid less. A few lines get mashed together (e.g. `position:relativemargin-bottom:8px;`) and it doesn't escape MSIE filters (`filter:alpha(opacity = 70)`) which you need to do in less.

Answer (score 0):

There are several CSS to LESS converters online, such as [css2less.cc](http://css2less.cc/) or [lessify](http://leafo.net/lessphp/lessify). They will convert your classic CSS to LESS syntax, which is what I understand you are trying to do.

Comment: I mentioned css2less in my question, but lessify also chokes on the amount of CSS I give it.